# Why is are my .Net 6 files in my SingleFile .exe not signed?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a minimal not-working example where I would like to create a .Net 6/8 `singleFile` .exe that extracts all dll's at runtime into %temp%. During build/publish, I would like to sign all .Net 6/8 dll's with my own signature.

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
    <BaseOutputPath>Build\bin</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="SignIntermediates" BeforeTargets="GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems">
    <Exec Command="Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -file &quot;path\to\my\signFiles.ps1&quot;" Condition="$(ConfigurationName) == Release" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The .exe is generated. All dll's are packed into it. The Powershell signs all .Net 6 dll's in the `win-x86` folder with my signature. When I start the .exe, all .Net 6 dll's are extracted into the local `%temp%` folder, however, those extracted dll's do not have my signature.

It feels like I am almost there, but some small detail is missing. Am I signing the wrong files? I am signing the files too late?